# MySQL query base on availibility of in another table

Tags: mysql, subquery

I'm brand new in MySQL and I need some help how to build simple query. I need to get  some result selecting "filtered" data from one table linked with another table based on conditions inside this second table.

In the first table named "**categories**" with following data inside:

| CategoryID | CategoryName |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | food |
| 2 | drinks |
| 3 | sweets |

In the second table named "**product**" there are following records:

| product | CategoryID | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| apple | 1 | 5 |
| banana | 1 | 0 |
| vodka | 2 | 0 |
| beer | 2 | 10 |
| chocolate | 3 | 0 |
| biscuits | 3 | 0 |

Both tables are linked by the column **CategoryID**.

I would like to build a query to return as results **only** the categories / CategoryName/, where there are products under this category  with **Quantity>0**.

Expected result is:

| CategoryName |
| --- |
| food |
| drinks |

Comment: What have you already tried and where exactly are you stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT categories.CategoryName
FROM
    categories
JOIN product ON product.CategoryID = categories.CategoryID
WHERE
    product.Quantity > 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT categories.CategoryName
FROM categories
JOIN product ON product.CategoryID =categories.CategoryID
WHERE product.Quantity > 0;